# InnerBlocks renderAppender doesn't do anything

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to add a custom appender to my InnerBlocks component. I followed the example here: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-editor/src/components/inner-blocks

However, nothing changes when I use this code. Am I missing something or has this functionality just not been released yet?

Here's my code, but it's exactly the same as the example.

```
<InnerBlocks
  renderAppender={ () => (
    <button className="bespoke-appender" type="button">Some Special Appender</button>
  ) }
/>
```

Comment: I had the same impression when I tried using it

Comment: As it’s in the master branch it should be available in the latest version of the Gutenberg PLUGIN

Comment: Yup, downloaded the plugin and it's working. Thanks.

Comment: Still having the same problem with the official WP included Gutenberg w/o plugin. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @niklas either have to download the plugin or wait for the next wordpress core release

Comment: Or is there a way to include the functionality in one of my plugins by importing the correct dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56739884/innerblocks-renderappender-doesnt-do-anything#comment100176266_56739884), the code example works as expected in newer versions of Gutenberg as of June 2019.